# 0.2.11: testing pyaudio using pytest

Tags: python, linux, pytest, pyaudio

I'm trying to package your module as an rpm package. So I'm using the typical PEP517 based build, install and test cycle used on building packages from non-root account.

- `python3 -sBm build -w --no-isolation`
- because I'm calling `build` with `--no-isolation` I'm using during all processes oly locally installed modules
- install .whl file in </install/prefix>
- run pytest with PYTHONPATH pointing to sitearch and sitelib inside </install/prefix>

By default pytest is not able to find any units however I found that after passing path tests/*.py it is able to find something.

Maybe someone can help prepare pyaudio to be able to test it using pytest?

Here is pytest output:

```
+ PYTHONPATH=/home/tkloczko/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/python-pyaudio-0.2.11-13.fc35.x86_64/usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages:/home/tkloczko/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/python-pyaudio-0.2.11-13.fc35.x86_64/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages
+ /usr/bin/pytest -ra tests/error_tests.py tests/pyaudio_tests.py
=========================================================================== test session starts ============================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.12, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/tkloczko/rpmbuild/BUILD/PyAudio-0.2.11
collected 23 items

tests/error_tests.py F..F.......FF                                                                                                                                   [ 56%]
tests/pyaudio_tests.py FFFFFFFFFF                                                                                                                                    [100%]

================================================================================= FAILURES =================================================================================
_______________________________________________________________ PyAudioErrorTests.test_error_negative_frames _______________________________________________________________

self = <error_tests.PyAudioErrorTests testMethod=test_error_negative_frames>

    def test_error_negative_frames(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
>           stream = self.p.open(channels=1,
                                 rate=44100,
                                 format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                                 input=True)

tests/error_tests.py:60:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
../../BUILDROOT/python-pyaudio-0.2.11-13.fc35.x86_64/usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pyaudio.py:750: in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

    def __init__(self,
                 PA_manager,
                 rate,
                 channels,
                 format,
                 input=False,
                 output=False,
                 input_device_index=None,
                 output_device_index=None,
                 frames_per_buffer=1024,
                 start=True,
                 input_host_api_specific_stream_info=None,
                 output_host_api_specific_stream_info=None,
                 stream_callback=None):
        """
        Initialize a stream; this should be called by
        :py:func:`PyAudio.open`. A stream can either be input, output,
        or both.

        :param PA_manager: A reference to the managing :py:class:`PyAudio`
            instance
        :param rate: Sampling rate
        :param channels: Number of channels
        :param format: Sampling size and format. See |PaSampleFormat|.
        :param input: Specifies whether this is an input stream.
            Defaults to ``False``.
        :param output: Specifies whether this is an output stream.
            Defaults to ``False``.
        :param input_device_index: Index of Input Device to use.
            Unspecified (or ``None``) uses default device.
            Ignored if `input` is ``False``.
        :param output_device_index:
            Index of Output Device to use.
            Unspecified (or ``None``) uses the default device.
            Ignored if `output` is ``False``.
        :param frames_per_buffer: Specifies the number of frames per buffer.
        :param start: Start the stream running immediately.
            Defaults to ``True``. In general, there is no reason to set
            this to ``False``.
        :param input_host_api_specific_stream_info: Specifies a host API
            specific stream information data structure for input.

            .. only:: pamac

               See :py:class:`PaMacCoreStreamInfo`.

        :param output_host_api_specific_stream_info: Specifies a host API
            specific stream information data structure for output.

            .. only:: pamac

               See :py:class:`PaMacCoreStreamInfo`.

        :param stream_callback: Specifies a callback function for
            *non-blocking* (callback) operation.  Default is
            ``None``, which indicates *blocking* operation (i.e.,
            :py:func:`Stream.read` and :py:func:`Stream.write`).  To use
            non-blocking operation, specify a callback that conforms
            to the following signature:

            .. code-block:: python

               callback(in_data,      # recorded data if input=True; else None
                        frame_count,  # number of frames
                        time_info,    # dictionary
                        status_flags) # PaCallbackFlags

            ``time_info`` is a dictionary with the following keys:
            ``input_buffer_adc_time``, ``current_time``, and
            ``output_buffer_dac_time``; see the PortAudio
            documentation for their meanings.  ``status_flags`` is one
            of |PaCallbackFlags|.

            The callback must return a tuple:

            .. code-block:: python

                (out_data, flag)

            ``out_data`` is a byte array whose length should be the
            (``frame_count * channels * bytes-per-channel``) if
            ``output=True`` or ``None`` if ``output=False``.  ``flag``
            must be either :py:data:`paContinue`, :py:data:`paComplete` or
            :py:data:`paAbort` (one of |PaCallbackReturnCodes|).
            When ``output=True`` and ``out_data`` does not contain at
            least ``frame_count`` frames, :py:data:`paComplete` is
            assumed for ``flag``.

            **Note:** ``stream_callback`` is called in a separate
            thread (from the main thread).  Exceptions that occur in
            the ``stream_callback`` will:

            1. print a traceback on standard error to aid debugging,
            2. queue the exception to be thrown (at some point) in
               the main thread, and
            3. return `paAbort` to PortAudio to stop the stream.

            **Note:** Do not call :py:func:`Stream.read` or
            :py:func:`Stream.write` if using non-blocking operation.

            **See:** PortAudio's callback signature for additional
            details: http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/portaudio_8h.html#a8a60fb2a5ec9cbade3f54a9c978e2710

        :raise ValueError: Neither input nor output are set True.
        """

        # no stupidity allowed
        if not (input or output):
            raise ValueError("Must specify an input or output " + "stream.")

        # remember parent
        self._parent = PA_manager

        # remember if we are an: input, output (or both)
        self._is_input = input
        self._is_output = output

        # are we running?
        self._is_running = start

        # remember some parameters
        self._rate = rate
        self._channels = channels
        self._format = format
        self._frames_per_buffer = frames_per_buffer

        arguments = {
            'rate' : rate,
            'channels' : channels,
            'format' : format,
            'input' : input,
            'output' : output,
            'input_device_index' : input_device_index,
            'output_device_index' : output_device_index,
            'frames_per_buffer' : frames_per_buffer}

        if input_host_api_specific_stream_info:
            _l = input_host_api_specific_stream_info
            arguments[
                'input_host_api_specific_stream_info'
                ] = _l._get_host_api_stream_object()

        if output_host_api_specific_stream_info:
            _l = output_host_api_specific_stream_info
            arguments[
                'output_host_api_specific_stream_info'
                ] = _l._get_host_api_stream_object()

        if stream_callback:
            arguments['stream_callback'] = stream_callback

        # calling pa.open returns a stream object
>       self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
E       OSError: [Errno -9996] Invalid input device (no default output device)

../../BUILDROOT/python-pyaudio-0.2.11-13.fc35.x86_64/usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pyaudio.py:441: OSError
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stderr call ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: Permission denied
ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: Permission denied
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: Permission denied
ALSA lib conf.c:5701:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: Permission denied
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM sysdefault
ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: Permission denied
ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: Permission denied
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: Permission denied
ALSA lib conf.c:5701:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: Permission denied
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM sysdefault
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround40
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround41
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround50
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround51
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection terminated

ALSA lib pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_id returned error: Permission denied
ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: Permission denied
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: Permission denied
ALSA lib conf.c:5701:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: Permission denied
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM dmix
ALSA lib pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

[..]

_________________________________________________________________ PyAudioTests.test_get_stream_cpuload_gil _________________________________________________________________

self = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_get_stream_cpuload_gil>

    def setUp(self):
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        (self.loopback_input_idx,
         self.loopback_output_idx) = self.get_audio_loopback()
>       assert (self.loopback_input_idx is None
                or self.loopback_input_idx >= 0), "No loopback device found"
E       AssertionError: No loopback device found
E       assert (-1 is None or -1 >= 0)
E        +  where -1 = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_get_stream_cpuload_gil>.loopback_input_idx
E        +  and   -1 = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_get_stream_cpuload_gil>.loopback_input_idx

tests/pyaudio_tests.py:33: AssertionError
_____________________________________________________________ PyAudioTests.test_get_stream_read_available_gil ______________________________________________________________

self = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_get_stream_read_available_gil>

    def setUp(self):
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        (self.loopback_input_idx,
         self.loopback_output_idx) = self.get_audio_loopback()
>       assert (self.loopback_input_idx is None
                or self.loopback_input_idx >= 0), "No loopback device found"
E       AssertionError: No loopback device found
E       assert (-1 is None or -1 >= 0)
E        +  where -1 = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_get_stream_read_available_gil>.loopback_input_idx
E        +  and   -1 = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_get_stream_read_available_gil>.loopback_input_idx

tests/pyaudio_tests.py:33: AssertionError
__________________________________________________________________ PyAudioTests.test_get_stream_time_gil ___________________________________________________________________

self = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_get_stream_time_gil>

    def setUp(self):
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        (self.loopback_input_idx,
         self.loopback_output_idx) = self.get_audio_loopback()
>       assert (self.loopback_input_idx is None
                or self.loopback_input_idx >= 0), "No loopback device found"
E       AssertionError: No loopback device found
E       assert (-1 is None or -1 >= 0)
E        +  where -1 = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_get_stream_time_gil>.loopback_input_idx
E        +  and   -1 = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_get_stream_time_gil>.loopback_input_idx

tests/pyaudio_tests.py:33: AssertionError
_____________________________________________________________ PyAudioTests.test_get_stream_write_available_gil _____________________________________________________________

self = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_get_stream_write_available_gil>

    def setUp(self):
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        (self.loopback_input_idx,
         self.loopback_output_idx) = self.get_audio_loopback()
>       assert (self.loopback_input_idx is None
                or self.loopback_input_idx >= 0), "No loopback device found"
E       AssertionError: No loopback device found
E       assert (-1 is None or -1 >= 0)
E        +  where -1 = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_get_stream_write_available_gil>.loopback_input_idx
E        +  and   -1 = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_get_stream_write_available_gil>.loopback_input_idx

tests/pyaudio_tests.py:33: AssertionError
_________________________________________________________________ PyAudioTests.test_input_output_blocking __________________________________________________________________

self = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_input_output_blocking>

    def setUp(self):
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        (self.loopback_input_idx,
         self.loopback_output_idx) = self.get_audio_loopback()
>       assert (self.loopback_input_idx is None
                or self.loopback_input_idx >= 0), "No loopback device found"
E       AssertionError: No loopback device found
E       assert (-1 is None or -1 >= 0)
E        +  where -1 = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_input_output_blocking>.loopback_input_idx
E        +  and   -1 = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_input_output_blocking>.loopback_input_idx

tests/pyaudio_tests.py:33: AssertionError
_________________________________________________________________ PyAudioTests.test_input_output_callback __________________________________________________________________

self = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_input_output_callback>

    def setUp(self):
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        (self.loopback_input_idx,
         self.loopback_output_idx) = self.get_audio_loopback()
>       assert (self.loopback_input_idx is None
                or self.loopback_input_idx >= 0), "No loopback device found"
E       AssertionError: No loopback device found
E       assert (-1 is None or -1 >= 0)
E        +  where -1 = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_input_output_callback>.loopback_input_idx
E        +  and   -1 = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_input_output_callback>.loopback_input_idx

tests/pyaudio_tests.py:33: AssertionError
____________________________________________________________________ PyAudioTests.test_stream_state_gil ____________________________________________________________________

self = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_stream_state_gil>

    def setUp(self):
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        (self.loopback_input_idx,
         self.loopback_output_idx) = self.get_audio_loopback()
>       assert (self.loopback_input_idx is None
                or self.loopback_input_idx >= 0), "No loopback device found"
E       AssertionError: No loopback device found
E       assert (-1 is None or -1 >= 0)
E        +  where -1 = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_stream_state_gil>.loopback_input_idx
E        +  and   -1 = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_stream_state_gil>.loopback_input_idx

tests/pyaudio_tests.py:33: AssertionError
______________________________________________________________________ PyAudioTests.test_system_info _______________________________________________________________________

self = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_system_info>

    def setUp(self):
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        (self.loopback_input_idx,
         self.loopback_output_idx) = self.get_audio_loopback()
>       assert (self.loopback_input_idx is None
                or self.loopback_input_idx >= 0), "No loopback device found"
E       AssertionError: No loopback device found
E       assert (-1 is None or -1 >= 0)
E        +  where -1 = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_system_info>.loopback_input_idx
E        +  and   -1 = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_system_info>.loopback_input_idx

tests/pyaudio_tests.py:33: AssertionError
_____________________________________________________________________ PyAudioTests.test_terminate_gil ______________________________________________________________________

self = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_terminate_gil>

    def setUp(self):
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        (self.loopback_input_idx,
         self.loopback_output_idx) = self.get_audio_loopback()
>       assert (self.loopback_input_idx is None
                or self.loopback_input_idx >= 0), "No loopback device found"
E       AssertionError: No loopback device found
E       assert (-1 is None or -1 >= 0)
E        +  where -1 = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_terminate_gil>.loopback_input_idx
E        +  and   -1 = <pyaudio_tests.PyAudioTests testMethod=test_terminate_gil>.loopback_input_idx

tests/pyaudio_tests.py:33: AssertionError
========================================================================= short test summary info ==========================================================================
FAILED tests/error_tests.py::PyAudioErrorTests::test_error_negative_frames - OSError: [Errno -9996] Invalid input device (no default output device)
FAILED tests/error_tests.py::PyAudioErrorTests::test_invalid_attr_on_closed_stream - OSError: [Errno -9996] Invalid input device (no default output device)
FAILED tests/error_tests.py::PyAudioErrorTests::test_read_overflow_exception - OSError: [Errno -9996] Invalid input device (no default output device)
FAILED tests/error_tests.py::PyAudioErrorTests::test_write_underflow_exception - OSError: [Errno -9996] Invalid output device (no default output device)
FAILED tests/pyaudio_tests.py::PyAudioTests::test_device_lock_gil_order - AssertionError: No loopback device found
FAILED tests/pyaudio_tests.py::PyAudioTests::test_get_stream_cpuload_gil - AssertionError: No loopback device found
FAILED tests/pyaudio_tests.py::PyAudioTests::test_get_stream_read_available_gil - AssertionError: No loopback device found
FAILED tests/pyaudio_tests.py::PyAudioTests::test_get_stream_time_gil - AssertionError: No loopback device found
FAILED tests/pyaudio_tests.py::PyAudioTests::test_get_stream_write_available_gil - AssertionError: No loopback device found
FAILED tests/pyaudio_tests.py::PyAudioTests::test_input_output_blocking - AssertionError: No loopback device found
FAILED tests/pyaudio_tests.py::PyAudioTests::test_input_output_callback - AssertionError: No loopback device found
FAILED tests/pyaudio_tests.py::PyAudioTests::test_stream_state_gil - AssertionError: No loopback device found
FAILED tests/pyaudio_tests.py::PyAudioTests::test_system_info - AssertionError: No loopback device found
FAILED tests/pyaudio_tests.py::PyAudioTests::test_terminate_gil - AssertionError: No loopback device found
======================================================================= 14 failed, 9 passed in 1.64s =======================================================================
```

Comment: BTW is it any plan top make new release?
Looks like last on was in 2017.

Comment: Is it any github/gitlab repo or mirror of the https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/git/pyaudio.git?